# Why modal view's (presented by detail view controller) presenting view controller is split view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a very simple split view controller with a master view controller and another detail view controller.

I put a modal segue between detail view controller and another view controller (A). When I inspect the A's presenting view controller, it is the split view controller instead of detail view controller.

My question is since the fact is detail view controller segued to A, why A's presenting view controller is split view controller?

Comment: Look at the UIViewController property, definesPresentationContext to see if that answers your question.

Comment: @DavidLiu is this why there is no 'back' button from A -> detail view (on iPad)?

Answer (score 0):

rdelmar is right, but I was still having this occur sporadically when placing definesPresentationContext in code and setting Presentation to Current Context in the storyboard.  I had to check Defines Context in the storyboard as well.

In short, the presenting view controller should have Presentation=Current Context, and a check beside Defines Context in storyboard.